# breadth first search traversal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tree

I know there're a few questions already up about this and I've already looked through them and tried to use those answers for a solution but I'm still having problems. For some reason my breadth search either gets stuck in an infinite loop or it says that it cannot `dequeue` from an empty list.

Here is the code

```
def enqueue(self, data):
    self.queue_list.append(data

def dequeue(self):
    return self.queue_list.pop(0)

def breadth(self):
    string = ""
    queue = q.Queue()
    root = self.root
    queue.enqueue(root.data)
    string += str(queue.dequeue())

    while queue != None:
        if root.left != None:
            queue.enqueue(root.left.data)
            root = root.left
        if root.right != None:
            queue.enqueue(root.right.data)
            root = root.right
        data = queue.dequeue()
        string += str(data)

    return string
```

Comment: Could you add your enqueue and dequeue methods?

It seems like the problem will be located inside one of those methods, most likely the dequeue.

Also what is `q` in this situation and what does `q.Queue()` do?

Comment: updated for those methods and I was just calling the module those are located in and initializing the queue.

Comment: In addition to wrong while loop condition, you are overriding your root in the first one if and while checking the second if condition it might be different than at the beginning of the loop, which is probably not you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push the node into the queue rather than just the data. You will only walk the right of the tree otherwise (the second if statement overwrites root).
I'm not sure about your data structure, so just using a collections.deque

```
from collections import deque

def breadth(self):
    string = ""
    q = deque([self.root])
    while q:
        node = q.popleft()
        string += str(node.data)
        if node.left:
            q.append(node.left)
        if node.right:
            q.append(node.left)
    return string
```

Comment: Thank you this lead me to the solution

Answer (score 2):

Your check in the `while` loop shouldn't be `queue != None`.

You should be checking for when the queue is empty. It's never going to be `None`.

As coded, you queue something then dequeue it, so the queue is empty, then you go into the `while` loop since although queue is empty, it is *not* `None`.

You then try to deque near the end of the while loop, which is causing your error.

Comment: His `q.Queue()` method might return `None` at some point. But you're definitely right that it won't become none if a queue was created.

Answer (score 0):

eventual solution using the tips above

```
 def breadth_first(self):

    string = ""
    queue = q.Queue()
    root = self.root
    queue.enqueue(root)

    while len(queue.queue_list) > 0:
        node = queue.dequeue()
        string += str(node.data) + " "
        if node.left != None:
            queue.enqueue(node.left)
        if node.right != None:
            queue.enqueue(node.right)
    return string
```